# Firedac: connection assigned to transactions

Tags: delphi, transactions, firebird, firedac

I'm using Delphi 10.4 with a Firebird-Database (3) and FireDac. I have a general question about transaction handling.

Please have a look at the following pseudo code:

```
write_transaction := TFDTransaction.Create;
write_connection := TFDConnection.Create;

write_transaction.Connection := write_connection;

write_connection.StartTransaction;
```

There is a connection assigned to a transaction. Then I start working with:

```
write_transaction.StartTransaction;
...
write_transaction.Commit;
```

But when I call **write_connection.StartTransaction** what will happen? So my questions...

Will there be started a transaction for the **write_transaction**, as if **write_transaction.StartTransaction** is called? Or will there be started a completely different transaction?

Answer (score 0):

> Will there be started a transaction for the write_transaction, as if
> write_transaction.StartTransaction is called?

Yes, this is the same. The TFDTransaction component wraps the transaction control functionality into a component. Practically, it offers the same transaction functionality as TFDConnection, but allows you to group commands and datasets by linking them to a specific transaction object.